# Listening for user inputs to to manipulate functions already running

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, input, global-variables

I have 2 files, `main.py` and `app.py`

**main.py**

```
import _thread
import time

def launch(thread_name):
    h = Hello()
    h.say_hello()

def input_reader(thread_name):
    global should_say_bye
    should_say_bye = False
    x = input()
    if x.lower() == "q":
        # Should run the say_bye() function from the Hello class. But using the same instance of the hello class from the launch() function
        should_say_bye = True
        print("Programming is about to quit.")

try:
    _thread.start_new_thread(launch, ("App",))
    _thread.start_new_thread(input_reader, ("Input_Reader",))
except:
    print("Error")

while 1:
    pass
```

**app.py**

```
import time

class Hello:
    def __init(self):
        pass

    def say_hello(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            print(f"Hello {i}")
            i += 1
            if should_say_bye = True:
                self.say_bye()
                should_say_bye = False
            time.sleep(2)

    def say_bye(self):
        print("Bye")
```

Basically I have 2 threads. One that runs the function `launch()` and one that listens to the console input (`input_reader()`). When it sees the the input `q` it should run the `say_bye()` function but ensuring its the same class instance as the `h` variable in the `launch()` function. I tried using a global variable `should_say_bye` so when `q` is detected it changes the global variable but that variable isn't defined in `Hello`

My goal is, run 1 thread with `launch()` and one thread with `input_reader()`. When `input_reader()` detects `q` it manipulates `launch()` but also the functions `launch()` is running side it like `say_hello()`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use globals due as they are highly unrecommended. Consider using a Pipe().

```
import _thread
import time
from multiprocessing import Pipe

class Hello():
    def __init(self):
        pass

    def say_hello(self,p1):
        i = 0
        while True:
            print(f"Hello {i}")
            i += 1
            check_pipe = p1.poll(0) #Checking pipe for stuff
            if check_pipe: #If there is something
                stuff = p1.recv() #We get it out
                if stuff == "q": #If it meets our conditio
                    self.say_bye()# we say bye
                break # and exit our loop? 
            time.sleep(2)

    def say_bye(self):
        print("Bye")


def launch(thread_name,pipe_output,kill_pipe): 
    h = Hello()
    h.say_hello(pipe_output)
    kill_pipe.send("kill") #You could pass the kill_pipe deeper
    kill_pipe.close() #Just formal closing.
    
def input_reader(thread_name,pipe_input):
    while True:
        x = input()
        if x.lower() == "q":
           
            pipe_input.send("q") #we put the input to the pipe
            print("Programming is about to quit.")
            pipe_input.close() #we close the pipe
            break

if __name__=="__main__": #Standard main block

    parent, child = Pipe() #initialize connection between input thread and launch 
    parent2, child2 = Pipe() #Initialize launch and kill command so no infinite loops.
    _thread.start_new_thread(launch, ("App",child,parent2)) #Simply pass the pipe connections
    _thread.start_new_thread(input_reader, ("Input_Reader",parent,))
    
    while True:
        check_kill = child2.poll(0) #Polling to see if the pipe has anything
        if check_kill: #Dont bother checking because pipe will only have kill command in it.
            print("ending program")
            break
        pass
```

This would work even if they are separate files as you can simply import Hello and pass the pipe connections to them.

Comment: I didn't know of this pipe thing before. How would I go about resetting the pipe? So after it says `say_bye()`, it resets the pipe. So essentially you can spam `q` in the console and when you do it executes `say_bye()`

Comment: Pipe works in FIFO. So if you don't close the pipe, you could keep sending stuff in on one end and receive on the other hand. See official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: multiprocessing.pipe is more limited (in terms of changing shared variables) and inefficient (duplicated classes, data) and slower (transfer data needed) compared to a thread because it starts another process. I don't think it should be used here, even if the performance of this code is not critical.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import _thread
import time

should_say_bye = False

class Hello:
    def __init(self):
        pass

    def say_hello(self):
        global should_say_bye
        i = 0
        while not should_say_bye:
            print(f"Hello {i}")
            i += 1
            time.sleep(2)
        self.say_bye()

    def say_bye(self):
        print("Bye")
        quit()

        
def launch(thread_name):
    h = Hello()
    h.say_hello()

def input_reader(thread_name):
    global should_say_bye
    should_say_bye = False
    x = input()
    if x.lower() == "q":
        # Should run the say_bye() function from the Hello class. But using the same instance of the hello class from the launch() function
        should_say_bye = True
        print("Programming is about to quit.")

try:
    _thread.start_new_thread(launch, ("App",))
    _thread.start_new_thread(input_reader, ("Input_Reader",))
except:
    print("Error")
```

You had used `if should_say_bye = True` and not set it as global

If you have a lot of flags like this, it might be better to use a class that you pass into multithreaded functions and set things.

```py
import _thread
import time

class Flags:
    stop_saying_hello = False

def say_hello(Flags):
    i = 0
    while not Flags.stop_saying_hello:
        print(f"Hello {i}")
        i += 1
        time.sleep(2)
        
def get_input(Flags):
    Flags.stop_saying_hello = (input().lower() ==  'q')
    
t1 = _thread.start_new_thread(say_hello, (Flags,))
t2 = _thread.start_new_thread(get_input, (Flags,))

while not Flags.stop_saying_hello:
    time.sleep(2)

print("bye")
```

Comment: How would I go about it if they are in 2 separate files? Do i need to import `should_say_buy`? If so, how do i do this

Comment: @Mikie Yes you will have to import it. If you are handling a lot of threads like this, then I would recommend making a class called Threading_Flags or Flags to contain the variable.